# Ambiguity of "ne ĝeni sin"

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity-reduction

I see *ne ĝenu vin fari tion* used sometimes to mean *don't bother doing that* but sometimes *don't hold back, feel free to do that* which is entirely the opposite sentiment!

For example, if someone says *ne ĝenu vin pro mi* I wouldn't be sure if they intended to mean *don't trouble yourself because of me* (don't do it) or *don't hold back because of me* (do it!)

Is one of these an incorrect usage or is it simply something that needs to be worked out from context?  Is there any way of phrasing these kinds of statements to be less ambiguous?

Answer (score 5):

*Ĝeni* means *to hinder* and Zamenhof used *Ne ĝenu vin...* to mean "Don't hesitate to..." (literally, "Don't hinder yourself" = "Don't refrain from...")

So *ĝeni* is not an exact synonym of *bother, disturb, distract* (i.e. *malatentigi*), and the reflexive *ĝeni sin* was supposed to mean *refrain from*...

It is easy to see why *Ne ĝenu vin fari tion* can be interpreted as "Don't encumber yourself with that task" (i.e. *Ne ĝenu vin **per** fari tion*), especially given the existence of *Ne hezitu...* but it was not the original meaning. *Don't bother...* is more like *Ne faru al vi la klopodon...*

- *Ne hezitu [ĝenu vin] porti la pakaĵon supren.* Don't hesitate to carry the luggage up.
- *Ne klopodu porti la pakaĵon supren.* Don't bother carrying the luggage up.
- *Ne tedu ilin.* Don't bother [bore] them.

Notice that "Don't bother about me" can be used in English both for encouragement and dissuasion and is thus similarly ambiguous out of context. My suggestion however is to avoid the Zamenhofian *ĝeni sin* and use *heziti* ("hesitate") or *deteni sin* ("refrain") instead.